# Natural Log Functions Integration

Tags: calculus, integration, substitution

I've found that $\ln(|\tan(x)|)$ is the solution.
I need help evaluating this problem.

[image]

Attempts:

[image]

$du = (-\csc(x)\cot(x)-\csc^2(x))dx$

Comment: Please show your attempts, thanks!

Comment: It is in your best interest that you type your posts (using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)) instead of posting links to pictures.

Comment: here are my attempts: https://i.stack.imgur.com/N8eQA.png

Comment: Your obtained answer is correct.

Answer (score 1):

To solve the integral of $\csc(x)$, begin by multiplying it by $\frac{\csc(x)+\cot(x)}{\csc(x)+\cot(x)}$.

Now, the integrand is $\frac{(\ (csx(x))\csc(x)+\cot(x)}{\csc(x)+\cot(x)}$

From there, substitute $u = \csc(x)+\cot(x)$, which would make $du = -\csc(x)(\csc(x)+\cot(x) dx$, making $dx=\frac{1}{-csc(x)csc(x)+cot(x)}$.

This expression cancels out with the numerator of the integrand prior to the $u-substitution$ and the denominator of the fraction is just -($\csc(x)+\cot(x)$), or $-u$. Now, the integrand is just $\frac{1}{u}$, which is equal to the $-ln|u| + C$.

Finally, undo the u-substitution to get $$-ln|\csc(x)+\cot(x)| + C$$

Comment: Well explained(+1)